# Modify menu_block

Tags: theming, blocks

I want to add some html tags to specefic block in my site .
This is my block and bold one is the html tag i want to add .

```
    <div id="block-menu-block-1" class="block block-menu-block notactive contextual-links-region block-1 block-menu-block-1 even block-without-title .notactive" style="overflow: hidden; width: 398px;">
    <div class="block-inner clearfix" style="top: 0px;">
     **<span class="SOMething">**
    <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed">
    <div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="menu-block-wrapper menu-block-1 menu-name-menu-narmafzar parent-mlid-0 menu-level-1">
    <ul class="menu">
    <li class="first last leaf active menu-mlid-470">
    <a class="views-row active" href="/salamat/">something</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
**</span>**
    </div>
```

should i create a module and use `hook_block_view_alter` ?

Comment: Is your block use temeplate or its html located in function?

Comment: Have you already modified block.tpl.php? Just add a new template file called block--menu-block--1.tpl.php and do your changes there.

Comment: thx a million dudes :)

Comment: @PontusNilsson Is, in this context, block--menu-block--1.tpl.php also the way to change the classes given to menu and menu links? Or what would you recommend?